# Improve performance of Visio automation from .net - creating diagram with lots of shapes and shape data

Tags: .net, com, visio

I have some code which creates potentially lots of shapes and sets shape data to various values. Some shapes might have 5 shape data rows, and some 20 (or various other values).

This is written in VB.Net and I would like to improve performance. Following guidelines here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mailant/archive/2004/09/22/233082.aspx

I have been looking at calls to .DropMany and .SetFormulas.

One issue is that I want to add lots of Shape Data rows - while there exists an .AddShapes call to do multiple rows in one hit, there is no equivalent for shape data section - leaving multiple calls to .AddNamedRow (I have tried calls to AddRows but it gives an error when used with Shape Data section).

Current algorithm:

```
Work out which masters to use for which shapes (not all the same)
pg.DropMany(with array of masters and appriate X/Y coords)
for each shape dropped:
    for each shape data row (e.g. 5 - 10 times per shape):
        shp.AddNamedRow()
pg.SetFormulas(for all shapes on page and all properties)
```

Any other suggestions for improving performance?

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding named rows to the instances you've just dropped rather than adding to the master prior to dropping the shapes?

Comment: The problem is that shapes with the same master **may** contain different sets of custom properties. I will have a poke around at finding out the minimum set of properties and perhaps setting those on the master prior to dropping.

Comment: ok, well I guess if you can get to a point where all the rows are present, then you could just toggle the visibility of the appropriate row/s.  Another downside to adding rows to an instance shape is that you'll make the entire section local (rather than inheriting from the master).

Comment: I presume that things need to be local if every custom property might have a different value?

Comment: Only the custom property values that are different from the the master need to be local, the rest are inherited.  But, if you add a custom property row to an instance shape then all of the rows become local, whether their values are different or not.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you might try is to use the [ScreenUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms428342.aspx) property on the Visio application object. When set to False, Visio will not update its window until the property is set to True again. I've not used Visio automation before but I have used this with Word and it helps a lot. The trick is to find a good trade-off between speed and frequency of updates-- if you turn off updating for too long, the user might think Visio has crashed.

Comment: Thanks - do this already - create an Invisible Visio app and then make it visible at the end.

Comment: Thanks, this reduced time from 3 mins to 30 secs. I use InvisibleApp

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at [DeferRecalc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765646.aspx), [LiveDynamics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769143.aspx), [AutoLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767982.aspx) and [UndoEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766384.aspx) (all properties of the Application object) depending on what your Shape Data is tied to.

Comment: Thanks John. Already using DeferRecalc. Will check and see if the other things make a difference.